# Paste with middle mouse stop working

Tags: mouse

I used to paste clicking the middle mouse button but it has stopped working since some days. Why? Can I reactivate it?

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently an upstream Ubuntu bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1581088